# Non-linear color distribution over the range of values in a geom_raster

Tags: r, ggplot2, geospatial

I'm faced with the following problem: a few extreme values are dominating the colorscale of my `geom_raster` plot. An example is probably more clear (note that this example only works with a recent ggplot2 version, I use 0.9.2.1):

```
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape)
theme_set(theme_bw())

m_small_sd = melt(matrix(rnorm(10000), 100, 100))
m_big_sd = melt(matrix(rnorm(100, sd = 10), 10, 10))
new_xy = m_small_sd[sample(nrow(m_small_sd), nrow(m_big_sd)), c("X1","X2")]
m_big_sd[c("X1","X2")] = new_xy
m = data.frame(rbind(m_small_sd, m_big_sd))
names(m) = c("x", "y", "fill")

ggplot(m, aes_auto(m)) + geom_raster() + scale_fill_gradient2()
```

[image]

Right now I solve this by setting the values over a certain quantile equal to that quantile:

```
qn = quantile(m$fill, c(0.01, 0.99), na.rm = TRUE)
m = within(m, { fill = ifelse(fill < qn[1], qn[1], fill)
                fill = ifelse(fill > qn[2], qn[2], fill)})
```

[image]

This does not really feel like an optimal solution. What I would like to do is have a non-linear mapping of colors to the range of values, i.e. more colors present in the area with more observations. In `spplot` I could use `classIntervals` from the `classInt` package to calculate the appropriate class boundaries:

```
library(sp)
library(classInt)
gridded(m) = ~x+y
col = c("#EDF8B1", "#C7E9B4", "#7FCDBB", "#41B6C4", 
        "#1D91C0", "#225EA8", "#0C2C84", "#5A005A")
at = classIntervals(m$fill, n = length(col) + 1)$brks
spplot(m, at = at, col.regions = col)
```

[image]

To my knowledge it is not possible to hardcode this mapping of colors to class intervals like I can in `spplot`. I could transform the `fill` axis, but as there are negative values in the `fill` variable that will not work.

So my question is: are there any solutions to this problem using ggplot2?

Comment: i've just become aware of this question, so I'll add a link to a related query I made a while ago: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18036849/gradient-colour-scale-with-gamma-parameter

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Seems that ggplot (0.9.2.1) and scales (0.2.2) bring all you need (for your original `m`):

```
library(scales)

qn = quantile(m$fill, c(0.01, 0.99), na.rm = TRUE)
qn01 <- rescale(c(qn, range(m$fill))) 

ggplot(m, aes(x = x, y = y, fill = fill)) + 
   geom_raster() + 
   scale_fill_gradientn (
      colours = colorRampPalette(c("darkblue", "white", "darkred"))(20),
      values = c(0, seq(qn01[1], qn01[2], length.out = 18), 1)) +
   theme(legend.key.height = unit (4.5, "lines"))
```

[image: resulting plot]

Comment: I was going to point out that you can build your own color palette with any scaling you want, but this looks like an easier way by far.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft: I used to do that, but then I had to look up the help for `scale_fill_gradientn` (because I tried to put the colours into `values`)...

Comment: Painful! I'd like to see a scale_*_gradient function that just took values and colours, and interpolated.

Comment: @Spacedman: tell Hadley. You can tell him a +1 from me for scales with `trim_quantiles` parameters... ;-)

Comment: +1 This is beautiful. `scales` has a ton of useful methods e.g. `scales::gradient_n_pal(...)` and transformations e.g. `log1p_trans, squish_infinite`